# Obtain a property or using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to access the onClick property of the button shown below using Puppeteer.

My code is as follows:

```
const pfButton = await sfwFram.$x('//input[@value="T&V Checklist - Browser"]');

console.log(pfButton);
```

I have the correct element because i'm able to click it.

```
await pfButton[0].click();
```

The console output is as follows:

```
[
  ElementHandle {
    _disposed: false,
    _context: ExecutionContext {
      _client: [CDPSession],
      _world: [DOMWorld],
      _contextId: 51
    },
    _client: CDPSession {
      eventsMap: [Map],
      emitter: [Object],
      _callbacks: Map {},
      _connection: [Connection],
      _targetType: 'page',
      _sessionId: '93A9A7BA5726B88223938422C56624FD'
    },
    _remoteObject: {
      type: 'object',
      subtype: 'node',
      className: 'HTMLInputElement',
      description: 'input.svmxbtn.smallbtn.enabledbtn',
      objectId: '-5187625421942822803.51.5'
    },
    _page: Page {
      eventsMap: Map {},
      emitter: [Object],
      _closed: false,
      _timeoutSettings: [TimeoutSettings],
      _pageBindings: Map {},
      _javascriptEnabled: true,
      _workers: Map {},
      _fileChooserInterceptors: Set {},
      _client: [CDPSession],
      _target: [Target],
      _keyboard: [Keyboard],
      _mouse: [Mouse],
      _touchscreen: [Touchscreen],
      _accessibility: [Accessibility],
      _frameManager: [FrameManager],
      _emulationManager: [EmulationManager],
      _tracing: [Tracing],
      _coverage: [Coverage],
      _screenshotTaskQueue: [ScreenshotTaskQueue],
      _viewport: [Object]
    },
    _frameManager: FrameManager {
      eventsMap: [Map],
      emitter: [Object],
      _frames: [Map],
      _contextIdToContext: [Map],
      _isolatedWorlds: [Set],
      _client: [CDPSession],
      _page: [Page],
      _networkManager: [NetworkManager],
      _timeoutSettings: [TimeoutSettings],
      _mainFrame: [Frame]
    }
  }
]
```

I wouldn't mind just obtaining the outerHTML so I can parse it myself if that would be easier.

[image: Need the "onclick" property]

Comment: No, I'm able to click the element, but thats not the goal.  I want to return the "onclick" property

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need something like this:

```js
const [pfButton] = await sfwFram.$x('//input[@value="T&V Checklist - Browser"]');
const onClick = await page.evaluate(button => button.getAttribute('onclick'), pfButton);
```